# How to categorize data in a short and simple way?

Tags: r, categories, cut

I want to categorize birth years in a short and simple way. I tried `cut`, which looks pretty good already. However, I couldn't solve it perfectly yet.

Given two samples of birth years

```
set.seed(42)
s.even <- sample(2000:2015, 100, replace=TRUE)
s.odd <- sample(1998:2017, 100, replace=TRUE)
```

With the "even" sample, the output is quite ok:

```
df.even <- data.frame(birthyear=s.even, 
                      category=cut(s.even, 3,
                                   labels=c("youth", "young", "youngsters")))

> with(df.even, ftable(category, birthyear))
           birthyear 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015
category                                                                                            
youth                   8    4    5    7    5    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
young                   0    0    0    0    0    0    7    5    6    6    8    0    0    0    0    0
youngsters              0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    9    4    5    9    8
```

But with an "odd" sample the breaks are not placed at the right places, i.e. I want the first category to encompass `1998:2005`, and the second category `2006:2010`:

```
df.odd <- data.frame(birthyear=s.odd.s, 
                      category=cut(s.odd.s, 3,
                                   labels=c("youth", "young", "youngsters")))

> with(df.odd, ftable(category, birthyear))
           birthyear 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017
category                                                                                                                
youth                   3    3   10    6    3    3    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
young                   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    5    4    4    5    5    7    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
youngsters              0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2   11    9    5    2    8    2
```

So I tried to set the break points manually in this way:

```
> cut(s.odd.s, s.odd.s[c(1, 
+                        which(s.odd.s %% 5 == 0 & !duplicated(s.odd.s)), 
+                        length(s.odd.s))])
  [1] <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        (1998,2000] (1998,2000] (1998,2000] (1998,2000]
  [8] (1998,2000] (1998,2000] (1998,2000] (1998,2000] (1998,2000] (1998,2000] (1998,2000]
 [15] (1998,2000] (1998,2000] (2000,2005] (2000,2005] (2000,2005] (2000,2005] (2000,2005]
 [22] (2000,2005] (2000,2005] (2000,2005] (2000,2005] (2000,2005] (2000,2005] (2000,2005]
 [29] (2000,2005] (2000,2005] (2000,2005] (2000,2005] (2000,2005] (2000,2005] (2000,2005]
 [36] (2000,2005] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010]
 [43] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010]
 [50] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010]
 [57] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2005,2010] (2010,2015] (2010,2015]
 [64] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015]
 [71] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015]
 [78] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015]
 [85] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2010,2015] (2015,2017]
 [92] (2015,2017] (2015,2017] (2015,2017] (2015,2017] (2015,2017] (2015,2017] (2015,2017]
 [99] (2015,2017] (2015,2017]
Levels: (1998,2000] (2000,2005] (2005,2010] (2010,2015] (2015,2017]
```

But the `1998`s are somehow excluded:

```
> head(s.odd.s)
[1] 1998 1998 1998 1999 1999 1999
```

Anyway, maybe there is an option to set in `cut()` that I have missed? I would also like to start the three categories at will with the "even" break point, i.e. `1998:2004` `2005:2009` `2010:2017`.

Comment: For the question of how to include 1998, just use `include.lowest = TRUE`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Okay, this one's going to work.